# postfix NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from Recipient address rejected

Tags: postfix

I have setup Email filter appliance which utilises postfix.
postfix gives the following error in the logs

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-oln040092070044.outbound.protection.outlook.com[40.92.70.44]: 451 4.7.1 <info@infasys.co.uk>: Recipient address rejected: Greylisted for 5 minutes; from=<rehan_miah@hotmail.com> to=<info@infasys.co.uk> proto=ESMTP helo=<EUR03-AM5-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com>
```

below is my main.cf file contents

```
    alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-3.1.3/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-3.1.3/README_FILES
inet_protocols = ipv4

smtputf8_enable = no

meta_directory = /etc/postfix
shlib_directory = no
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
myorigin = $mydomain
relay_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
local_recipient_maps = 
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
default_destination_recipient_limit = 1
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.pem
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtp_tls_session_cache
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.pem
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_tls_session_cache
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_helo_restrictions = check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_access, reject_invalid_hostname
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_relay_restrictions = 
    permit_mynetworks, 
    permit_sasl_authenticated, 
    defer_unauth_destination hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:2501
masquerade_domains = $mydomain
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/dhparam.pem
smtpd_tls_ciphers = low
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `postfix` [greylisted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting) sender. You need to wait until outlook servers will make another delivery attempt.

Comment: i just included the main.cf file i am now getting recipent address rejected having modified the transport map to include the domain. any further help. thanks

Comment: I misread your initial error message. I have updated my answer.